# error while uploading file to php server using retroft android

Tags: php, android

I tried to upload a file to my server using retroft android.

My problem is when I upload a file it doesn't work but it works when I upload an image? 
How can I solve this problem ?

upload Function

```
private void uploadImage() {

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.wait_plz));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            API_POST service = RetroClient.getApiService();
            File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(),
    requestFile);
            Call<Result> resultCall = service.uploadImageSTudyPlain(body);
            resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Log.d("Status",response.body().getStatus()+"");
                        Log.d("msg",response.body().getMsg()+"");


                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

        });
```

select file from device

```
public void showImagePopup() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),1);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);

            if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set correct file type:

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(file.toURI())), 
    file);
```

Comment: thank you but file.toURI() have this error  Error:(423, 72) error: incompatible types: URL cannot be converted to Uri

Comment: Then I recommend to save `selectedFileUri` (make it field of class) in `onActivityResult` and use it instead of `file.toURI()`